# Как заставить объект двигаться?

Tags: java, javafx, разработка-игр

Новенький в JavaFX. Хочу сделать игру Xonix. Есть поле размером 1920 * 1080.  Сейчас проблема в том, что нужно заставить квадратик двигаться нажимая на кнопки вверх, вниз и т.д. Как это можно реализовать через JavaFX?

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте про [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)

Простой пример (без проверок на границы). Комментарии к этому коду тоже вроде не нужны:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        GameUnit gameUnit = new GameUnit(150, 0, 10, 10);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Pane(gameUnit), 300, 275);
        scene.setOnKeyPressed(gameUnit);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private static class GameUnit extends Rectangle implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

        public GameUnit(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
            super(x, y, width, height);
            setFill(Color.BLACK);
        }

        private void checkInitBehavior() {
            if ( behavior == null ) {
                behavior = new GameUnitBehavior();
                new Thread(behavior).start();
            }
        }
        private GameUnitBehavior behavior;

        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
            checkInitBehavior();
            switch (event.getCode()) {
                case LEFT:
                    behavior.moveToSide(Side.LEFT);
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    behavior.moveToSide(Side.RIGHT);
                    break;
                case UP:
                    behavior.moveToSide(Side.TOP);
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    behavior.moveToSide(Side.BOTTOM);
                    break;
            }
        }

        private class GameUnitBehavior extends Task {

            private boolean vertical = false;

            private boolean positiv = false;

            private double step = 10.0;

            @Override
            protected Object call() throws Exception {
                while ( getScene().getWindow().isShowing() ) {
                    if ( vertical ) {
                        setX(getX() + (positiv ? step : -step));
                    } else {
                        setY(getY() + (positiv ? step : -step));
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                return null;
            }

            public void moveToSide(Side side) {
                vertical = side.isVertical();
                positiv = side == (vertical ? Side.RIGHT : Side.BOTTOM );
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: А теперь с помощью этого кода, как мне сделать так. Есть поле, и когда квадратик проходит по нему, часть этого поля исчезает, как бы "отрезается"? Если не поняли, пожалуйста, можете посмотреть gameplay игры xonix. Буду очень благодарен

Comment: Вы можете на место "отрезанных" частей добавлять фигуры соответствующей формы и цветом, отличным от цвета основного фона. Или можно представить поле в виде маленьких квадратов, и менять цвет тех, которые должны быть "отрезаны" (в этом случае движение основного квадрата также будет закрашиванием элемента поля).